# Python Importing exact hexa value and display

Tags: python

I have the Data structure where I defined the list.

```
data_items = [  {"ID":0x0202,  "Name":"Country"},           
                { "ID":0x2007, "Name":"Sports"}]
```

I want to import complete 'ID' value including '0', like example:

```
'0202'
'2007'
```

Now it is printing as below:

```
'202'
'2007'
```

Code:

```
Input = 1
SMI = data_items[Input-1]['ID']
hex(SMI)[2:]
```

Suggest me how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) removes any leading zeros. If you want to maintain a length of 4 characters in the string, try doing `hex(SMI)[2:].zfill(4)` where it will ad leading zeros until it reaches the specified length.

Comment: Cortes, Working as expected

Comment: I'm glad, consider up voting my answer when you can. Good luck with your project

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SMI = data_items[Input-1]['ID']
SMI = str(SMI).split('0x')[1]
```